# How to access other method of an object when accessing it from a callback using prototype methods declarations?

Tags: javascript

A short and simple example to illustrate this long title (the question is commented):

(Let's admit we click a button on a HTML document where this javascript is associated to)

```
function AClass() {

}

AClass.prototype.stepOne = function() {
  console.log('stepOne');
  //How to call stepTwo() from here (since `this` refer to the button DOM Object element) ?
}

AClass.prototype.stepTwo = function() {
  console.log('stepTwo');
}

var A = new Aclass();

$('button').click(A.stepOne);
```

My first move was to declare a classical `var that = this` in the constructor, but since it's out of scope from the methods, is there a way to use this syntaxe when using methods as callbacks ?

Comment: May be `bind`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Cherniv: I was thinking the same thing, but when you fix the value of `this` to the instance then it will no longer be the DOM element, although you could access it from the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    A.stepOne();
});
```

now `stepOne` has the context of the A object

Comment: Yes that's what i finally did but i was wondering if there is a trick to avoid that

Comment: @Ludo: Not really. You could use `.bind` though. [Here is an article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

Create a closure by wrapping the call in an anonymous function.

```
$('button').click(function(){A.stepOne()});
```

Then simply call stepTwo from stepOne

```
AClass.prototype.stepOne = function() {
  console.log('stepOne');
  this.stepTwo();
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/wD68z/

Comment: Did you notice that this method (stepOne()) is called from a listener as a callback (so the "this" keyword point to the button DOM Object) ?

Comment: Very interesting ! I have never use the `call` method before, but we can only use it for a specific instance (here `A`) or could we make this behavior dynamical (reffering to the class)

Comment: @ludo That first attempt was wrong, I misread the question. The updated example works.